# How do I install ubuntu-desktop and compiz from root terminal?

Tags: compiz

I've messed up my computer trying to get a game to work because I thought uninstalling compiz would be a brilliant idea. Boy oh boy was I wrong. Now I get the message "Failed to load session "Ubuntu" whenever I try to log in. I've tried accessing a terminal using Cltrl-Alt-F1 but whenever I try to type in my username and password I get login incorrect.

So when the computer starts I hold shift on my keyboard and it loads Grub and takes me to this screen with the GNU GRUB version 2.00-13ubuntu3 at the top. I select Advance options for Ubuntu and hit enter and then I select Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-35-generic (recovery mode) then press enter.

There is an option that says root and I am able to get to a terminal through there. My first question is is it possible to fix my computer through this terminal. My second question is if it is possible what steps do I need to take to fix it ? My third question is what information do you need to help me and how can I access that information ?

Comment: So I tried that and this appeared twice: W: Failed to fetch http://extra.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.dists.raring.main/i18n.Translation-en_US Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 -System error)                                                       This popped up three times: W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com.linux.chrome.deb/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en_US Something wicked happend resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 -System Error)                             At the bottom it says: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old one...

Answer (score 0):

With `root` access, you should be able to reinstall Ubuntu Desktop with

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
```

As for getting compiz reinstalled, you might check out [this thread on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496852). Though it refers to reinstalling under Lucid, the principle should be the same.

Comment: HI, I tried typing that into the terminal and it said.

Comment: W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/ E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/ E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Filesystem is mounted in read-only. Try `mount -o remount,rw /` first, then see if you can run `apt-get`.

Comment: Hi, I tried that then it said Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Weird. Try running `apt-get update` prior to reinstalling.

Comment: So I tried that and this popped up twice: W: Failed to fetch http://extra.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.dists.raring.main/i18n.Translation-en_US Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 -System error) This popped up three tiems: W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-1386Packages Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 -System error) At the bottom it said E: Some index filed failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: I don't know how to go up in the terminal to give more lines but these lines were ones I could see.

Comment: Worried that might happen. You might check `ifconfig` to see if networking is up with a good IP address. If the networking is down, I'm at a loss as to how to point you from here.

Comment: I typed in ifconfig and this popped up: Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask: 255.0.0.0 inet6addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING   MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:6496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:6496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:513760 (513760 (513.7 KB) TX bytes:513760 (513.7 KB)

Comment: Yep, no `eth0` or other interfaces.. Only thing I can think of at this point is to boot from a live CD and try it from there.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help ! Hopefully I can find an Ubuntu CD in the near-future. In which case if I am having a hard time figuring out what to do from there I will update this thread to ask.